# How to get email Id's of all the recipients to which email delivery has been failed

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail API and i want to get email id's of all the recipients to which email delivery has failed.How to achieve this using this API.I used get all recipients option but it returns only the email id via which email is sent. I am using google SMTP server.Thanks!

Comment: I do not know much about java mail API but, (all recipients - recipients who received the mail = recipient who did not received the mail). isin't this the solution :)

Comment: My email address is xyz@gmail.com, when i execute the program and do getRecipients it gives me xyz@gmail.com only at the output.

Comment: In my opinion, the java mail API can only forward the mail request to your mailing server. The mail being sent to the recipient is not the concern of javax mailing API's. The server will save the mail request and will starting sending them (in will not be synchronous). Thus mail being sent of not can not be returned by the java mail API.

Comment: http://cases.azoft.com/implementing-notifications-using-javamail/

Comment: You have already asked this question before! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450796/how-to-track-email-delivery-status-using-javamail

Comment: that is for tracking weather email has delivered successfully or not and not for getting the failed recipients.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read these JavaMail FAQ entries:

- [If I send a message to a bad address, why don't I get a
  SendFailedException or TransportEvent indicating that the address is
  bad?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr)
- [When a message can't be delivered, a failure message is
  returned. How can I detect these "bounced" messages?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#bounce)

In addition, see the [smtpsend.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples), which will show you how to catch and process the exceptions thrown when sending a message, for those (rare) cases when the SMTP server reports the failure synchronously.